# QtTable Widget does not show values

Tags: python, qt4

I have a GUI application written in python using Qt4. When the button is pressed the application reads data from file and populates the TableWidget. The code is like this:

```
def fillList(self):
  if my_table.dict1:
    i = 0
    values = sorted(my_table.dict1.keys())
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(values))
    for value in values:
        self.fillRow(value, i)
        i += 1
  return

def fillRow(self, value, i):
  x = my_table.dict1[value]
  y = my_table.dict2[value]
  z = 0
  if y != 0:
    z = int(x / y)
  for a, b in zip(list(range(4)), (value, x, y, z)):
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, b)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, a, item)
  return
```

It works. The TableWidget has sorted enabled, but when you sort a column and press a button to read the file again and to populate the table, everything becomes a mess. Most cells remain randomly blank. I would appreciate any idea, how can I fix it.

Comment: Are you clearing the table ahead of populating it again?

Comment: I tried self.tableWidget.clear(), but it did no good.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by disabling sorting before populating the table and enabling it after.
so the first function will look now:

```
def fillList(self):
  if my_table.dict1:
  i = 0
  values = sorted(my_table.dict1.keys())
  self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
  self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(values))
  for value in values:
    self.fillRow(value, i)
    i += 1
  self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
  return
```